# Is the use of subjunctive here appropriate?

Tags: subjuntivo

I want to say:

> Me gusta viajar en avión porque es rápido pero una desventaja es que no sea cómodo.

Is the use of "sea" here appropriate (I think it may be because the subject changes)? Or should I replace it with "es"?

Comment: Note: the change-of-subject rule applies to subordinate clauses, not to independent clauses, and it alternates with the infinitive, not with the indicative. I've recently answered a question on the matter. You can check it out here: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16290/if-the-subject-doesnt-change-when-do-i-use-the-infinitive/16291#16291

Answer (score 1):

The phrase can be slightly modified to fit "es", "ser" and "sea", but in any case a comma is essential to follow the message. Some examples could be:

- Me gusta viajar en avión, pero es una desventaja que no sea cómodo.
- Me gusta viajar en avión, pero el que sea incómodo es una desventaja.
- Me gusta viajar en avión, pero tiene la desventaja de ser incómodo.
- Me gusta viajar en avión, aunque es incómodo.

I like the last one, because is very direct. For written language, the third option seems the most reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use "es"

Me gusta viajar en avión porque es rápido pero **tiene** una desventaja, **no es cómodo**

Anyways with "sea" everybody will understand you. But sound a little bit forced.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, 
One of the best ways to measure how much a person understands the spanish lenguage is by  how natural he sounds, you may know all of the grammar, all the structures, all the verb tenses and the like but, if you don't sound natural, any native speaker will soon know that you are not able to have a fluent conversation , my tip is "anytime you ask about a specific use between two words or sentences , just ask what the natural way to say it is" in this case , the natural one we always hear in our countries is  ME GUSTA MUCHO VIAJAR EN BARCO , LO UNICO MALO ES QUE NO ES MUY SEGURO.. it is super natural in any spanish speaking country.
Bye.